# If categories are so powerful, when is the proper time to subclass an iOS class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, associations, categories

With categories so powerful to add methods, along with [associations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/) that can add additional properties & ivars, it is really hard to see the significance of subclasses in Objective C.

With so many open source categories built in open source, I really see no significance of a subclass. Associations can also provide invocation chain (inside association property implementation), so there is no real need for inheritance.

Can anyone provide the exact use case when I want to create MyLabel extending UILabel, or MyString extending NSString?

Answer (score 4):

- Subclasses can **safely** override methods in the superclass; categories cannot.
- Subclasses customize behavior for only instances of the new class, and not for all instances of the superclass.
- Subclasses declare intent in a way that a collection of categories cannot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use subclassing if you don't want to extend existing classes.

Let's say that you want to be able to map your objects into JSON. If you extend `NSObject` via category, it will mean that all classes, subclassed from the `NSObject`, should has a bit of code like mapping rules. This is not a way to go, because almost all classes are subclasses of `NSObject`.

To avoid this, you have to implement JSON mapping in a subclass of `NSObject`. So, everybody will know that all instances of your subclass provide the necessary methods for mapping and work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms:

- Categories are used to **add** methods etc and apply to **all** instances of the superclass... So everything from a NSString as an example.
- A Subclasses can **add/override (change)** parts and can apply to **specific instances** of a class rather than everything from a NSString.